# Using EE to power a web app prototype

Tags: entries, users

I'm relatively new to EE and hoping it will for me to power a web app prototype I'm working on.

Is there anyway build a public front end that allows users to edit or publish entries without logging into EE? I've not been able to find any documentation would suggest this is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Safecracker used to be answer to this but now it is deprecated and replaced with "Expression Channel Form". Have a look at this. Hope this helps.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_form/index.html#logged-out-member-id